# Tracking and setting goals referral sites using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Using Google Analytics is it possible either by using goals or creating a custom chart to track month by month how much traffic a referal network site passes to my website?

I'd like to measure the traffic source from a paid directory service, let's say, Yell - so I want to see how much traffic each month comes to me from their site and ideally set a monthly target so I can monitor this ongoing.

Any help or direction with this would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goals are not necessary for this. Simply ask the referring website to add utm parameters to all links on their domain that point to your website. So if your website is www.example.com, any links on their website pointing to your domain would be www.example.com?utm_source=yelp&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=summer_2017. Once that is done, you would just check the Acquisition > All Traffic > Source/Medium report and you should see a row for "yelp/affiliate". For that row, one of the columns will be sessions, which tells you how much traffic they sent you for the selected time period. More info on campaign tracking can be found here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I'm guessing this request is pretty standard for referring websites as it helps justify their paid for service?